# Need spss count column

Tags: group-by, count, spss

I’m new in spss and i need to solve this problem:

I need to count the number of families that they have 1-2 members and the families who have 3-4 and the families who have 5 or more members , and classify them by the nationality

My data looks like

- fmaily_id / member_id  / nation
- 1      /   1      /    us
- 1      /   2      /    us
- 1     /    3      /    us
- 1      /   4       /   us
- 2    /     1     /     not us
- 2    /     2     /     not us
- 2    /     3     /     not us
- 2    /     4     /     not us
- 3    /     1     /     us
- 4    /     1      /    us
- 4    /     2     /     us
- 5    /     1     /     not us
- 5    /     2     /     not us

Comment: Look up the `aggregate` command. First you need to aggregate by family ID (and nation), counting the cases in each family. Now you can use `recode` command to classify families into the categories you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an `aggregate` command:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * 
/BREAK FAMILY_ID 
/N_IN_FAMILY = N(MEMBER_ID) 
/NATION_TITLE = FIRST(NATION). 
EXECUTE. 

LIST.
```

This will give you the following result:

```
FAMILY_ID |N_IN_FAMILY | NATION_TITLE
 1.00     |    4       |  US 
 2.00     |    4       |  NOT US 
 3.00     |    1       |  US 
 4.00     |    2       |  US 
 5.00     |    2       |  NOT US
```